# nix installation failure on mac with "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired"

Tags: nix, install

I'm trying to install nix on my macbook but I had following error message.
How can I fix this certificate expired problem?

macOS : High Sierra 10.13.6

Thanks in advance.

//-- error message ---

~ MyMac$ sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
HTTPS-proxy has similar options --proxy-cacert and --proxy-insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really Cardano question, but seems your Mac has problem with certificates.

Quick fix will be just to add `-k`, like this:

```
sh <(curl -k -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume
```

This will ignore certificate issue.

In longrun you need to dig dipper, maybe you need to reinstall your root certificates, or update your MacOS.

Maybe this will help:

https://www.digicert.com/blog/expired-intermediate-certificate

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. in fact I've tried to add -k option but it is not working as below. MyMac$ sh <(curl -k https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0, I'll dig into more as your help.

Comment: You forgot `-L` in your command. Just copy from here `sh <(curl -k -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume`

Comment: Yes, you're right. it seems working. thank you so much!

Comment: If it worked, I would appreciate if you will accept my answer as solution. Cheers!

Comment: sure, thank you.

Comment: I've also up-voted the answer but would caution against having non-Cardano questions here going forward.

Comment: I totally agree and I do think that non-Cardano question should not be here. I was tending to help, because OP wanted to install nix what is widely used in Cardano project, at lest per my understanding